# How to remove current year from wp_get_archives

Tags: custom-post-type-archives, date-time

Does anyone know how to exclude the current year from

```
$args = array(
    'limit'           => '',
    'format'          => 'html', 
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'show_post_count' => false,
    'echo'            => -1,
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'type' => 'yearly',
    'paged'=>$paged,
    'post_type'     => 'my_post_type'
    );
    wp_get_archives( $args );
```

This basically outputs all the years on my custom archive page. I want to exclude the current year from it.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the source code of `wp_get_archives` (line 1791 currently) the query is hardcoded. There is no filter to influence it. This means you have to correct the result afterwards. This is fairly easy if you set `echo => 0` in the args, so the result is returned in stead of echoed. Then all you have to do is remove the first link that is returned:

```
$pattern = "/<a.*?<\/a>/";
$replacement = "";
$archives = wp_get_archives ($args);
preg_replace ($pattern, $replacement, $archives, 1);
echo $archives;
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed the 1st child from the list using css. It really did the trick.